# How to conditionally require 18+ fields based on selection of two dropdowns

Tags: 2010, validation, ootb

I'm new to Sharepoint 2010 with what I would call a highschool freshman level of coding experience. I don't currently have access to Sharepoint designer, but from the searching I've done so far, it may required. Still I'm hoping to find an OOTB solution to the problem below.

I have been tasked with building a incident resolution tracking sheet on Sharepoint. My boss is very concerned with being audited by legal, and has some very specific requirements about required information. Column A contains a drop down list of 5 choices that indicate the Final Solution. Column B Contains a drop down list with 4 choices that indicate the Initial Problem. Based on The selections in A and B, different Columns in C-X are required to be blank, not blank, or contain specific entries. The only way I can find to do this is to create a list validation containing a nested if for each combination of A and B resulting in 20 nested ifs. However sharepoint is limited to 7 nested ifs, so I'm looking for any possible solutions.

*This List will primarily be accessed in Datasheet view, so HTML in calculated column type solutions are not viable.

Comment: I know it's inappropriate but I just have to comment how phrase "18+" in the title will attract many views to your post :)

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript? I have a solution using SPDesigner and javascript :)

Comment: As I said, I'm new, so I could be totally wrong, but it was my understanding that javascript can't affect datasheet view because of something to do with activeX controls, so any sort of html/javascript solutions aren't feasible. Am I incorrect about this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is simple, use JavaScript. I use it all the time in my projects to show or hide list items. All you need is to use the document.getElementById("your field ID").value; and do your logic following the selection in your drop down. To show or hide use the element style visibility. You can even control what is shown in your second drop down from what is selected in the first one.

Comment: As I said, I'm new, so I could be totally wrong, but it was my understanding that javascript can't affect datasheet view because of something to do with activeX controls, so any sort of html/javascript solutions aren't feasible. Am I incorrect about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add some calculated fields, maybe one for each main condition you need to test for. Anything to simplify your nested ifs. Put some of those nested ifs in the calculated columns.

Then, you can make the list validation use those calculated fields.

If you're being audited by legal, using the list validation is going to be the only way to satisfy them - at least it was ours. What you do with that also carries over into quick edit, so users can't get around the limitations.